# SSRS - Filtering an Integer With Both a String and a Boolean Parameter

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

I have a Boolean parameter called WLH where if True then it should ignore everything but if False then it should show a 0 for every craft textbox in a row that has the word "LABORER" in it. This is the expression that I am using but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Can I get help on making it work? What am I doing wrong?

```
=IIF(Parameters!WLH.Value = false AND ReportItems!craft.Value LIKE "*laborer*", 0, ---main calculation for the else statement---)
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things I see with this expression that need closer attention.

1. **Parameters!WLH.Value = CBool("false")**: The false side of the equality test needs to be converted to a boolean type with the CBool (conver to boolean) function.
2. **ReportItems!craft.Value.IndexOf("laborer") >= 0**:  SSRS doesn't support LIKE in expressions but we can test for the existance of a substring in this manner.  What this is doing is looking for the index (where the string "laborer" starts) in the field value and checking for a value greater than 0. This would mean that "laborer" was found while a value other than a positive integer means that the string "laborer" was not found.

I don't have SSRS installed on this machine to double check so post a comment if you still need help.  Also note that IndexOf is case sensitive and that if you want to match to "Laborer" as well, you will have to do a case conversion prior to the IndexOf.

Full expression:

```
=IIF(Parameters!WLH.Value = CBool("false") AND ReportItems!craft.Value.IndexOf("laborer") >= 0, 0, ---main calculation for the else statement---)
```

**EDIT**: To deal with case sensitivity
Use "UCase()" to convert your field to upper case and then test only against "LABORER".

```
=IIF(Parameters!WLH.Value = CBool("false") AND UCase(ReportItems!craft.Value).IndexOf("LABORER") >=0, 0, ---main calculation for the else statement---)
```

Comment: Okay I didn't know that SSRS didn't support the LIKE filter like TSQL does, but your new expression looks like it might work. However there is just one little problem. With LIKE it doesn't matter what cases the word is used, but with your new expression, it might not work all the time since sometimes the craft can either be LABORER, laborer, or Laborer. Do the cases in the index really have to be exact? Or is there a way to make it look for all 3 variables?